# Dynamically add new tasks after gather(*tasks)

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio

For example this code:

```
async def f1(num):
    while True:
        print(num)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

class ExampleClass:
  def __init__():
     self.tasks = []

  async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(f1(i)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

  def add_new_task(task):
      self.tasks.append(task)
```

Then somewhere outside I call

```
ExampleClass.add_new_task(task)
```

What I need is to add new tasks and execute them asynchronously with the existing ones.

May be I should use any other constructions to implement what i want?
What is important is that my tasks probably need to execute forever(forever polling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I come to possible solution for my case with the idea of [Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74716923/dynamically-add-new-tasks-after-gathertasks/74745496#74745496).
The approximate idea is to use fake async linfinite loop where all my task are executed and where I update new tasks within **asyncio.TaskGroup** :

```
   async def fake_generator():
        while True:
            yield None

    fake_gen = fake_generator()
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:

        async for _ in fake_gen:
            await add_new_data()

            for element in self.data:
                if not self.data[element]['in_use']:
                    tg.create_task(job(element))
                    self.data[element]['in_use'] = True

            await asyncio.sleep(60 * 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `asyncio.gather` function is not really convenient for such task. However, you can take a look at [`asyncio.TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) which was released in Python3.11 and allows to add new tasks dynamically more easily.

```py
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import wait, FIRST_COMPLETED


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
        # Create some tasks
        tasks = [
            group.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1.0))
            for _ in range(10)
        ]
        
        # Wait for some tasks to finish
        done, tasks = await wait(tasks, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)

        # Add more tasks (/!\ `tasks` is now a set)
        tasks.add(group.create_task(asyncio.sleep(2.0)))
       
       # Wait the rest to complete 
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```